# magento mixed content after ssl installed

Tags: magento, http, ssl, https, mixed-content

I recently installed a godaddy ssl certificate on my magento site. My home page loads fine with no mixed content. However, all the links in the navigation menu are being generated as http:// and the cart page has mixed content warnings. 
My config is:
Auto redirect to base url: no
use web server rewrites: no
use secure urls in frontend: yes
use secure urls in admin: yes
offloader header: SSL_OFFLOADED

How do I get rid of all the mixed content? Which files do I need to change?

Comment: You can see those file in `firebug`. It's an browser plugin.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but a tool you can now use to track down mixed content issues is: https://httpschecker.net/how-it-works

Answer (score -1):

The unsecure URL under:

System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure

needs to be changed to https:// instead of http://. This fixed the issue.

Comment: this is an ugly work around, you should just set use SSL in frontent to true

Comment: Agree, this is not a good solution. But what is a good solution for a SSL terminated proxy. Setting `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to `on` has worked for me in the past but doesn't have any effect here

Comment: The value for my `web/unsecure/base_url` starts with `https`, and I still get this error...